# ssh public key copying

Tags: ssh

This question is repeating from Stack Overflow because i don't get answer from there.

I'm trying to make a simple script that will import the public key to other servers.

I have made 2 options you can choose. One is using ssh-copy-id, and the other is simple copy the pub key to the file on the other server. The second one works ok but I cant make this to work wiht ssh-copy-id. This is what I have for now:

```
ssh-copy-id -i $var1 $i
```

Where $var1 is "/path/to/the/public_key.pub" and $i is the servers where they are written in a txt file. The whole idea is I have my pub keys everywhere and I like to enter the pub key of a new admin guy everywhere. And it works ok but when I execute I have to enter my password. Any solution to do this with one time entering the password. And also I like to enter new line before adding the key. But I can't find solution how to do this with ssh-copy-id

Comment: Please delete the question on stack overflow so that this one doesn't get closed.

Comment: You don't want to be asked for a password for each server it copies to?

Comment: That's the impression I got.  From the manual page: "ssh-copy-id is a script that uses ssh(1) to log into a remote machine (presumably using a login password, so password authentication should
be enabled, unless you've done some clever use of multiple identities).  It assembles a list of one or more fingerprints and tries to log in with each key, to see if any of them are already installed." -- Naturally, if the public key is not already at the remote place, this means a lot of password typing.

Comment: The duplicate on SO is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24981679/ssh-public-key-copying) ... Random folks: I suggest if you have enough rep on SO, vote to close that one. It's not even on-topic there... Leave this copy open.

Comment: I delete the post from Overflow. Yes, i have ubuntu and my private key with public also are stored in /root/.ssh/pub and priv. My key is on every server. I like when new key is change or add to add on all servers in authorized_keys. I have put servers in on file and loop through them executing the command above. But every session, command executed is asking me for password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is this.

1) On your terminal, create an array with all hosts/IP addresses you want to copy the id_rsa.pub. For example

```
hosts=( host1 host2 192.168.100.200 host4 )
```

2)  Create the expect file  save it and make it executable using `chmod +x filename`

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

if { $argc != 4 } {
    puts stderr "usage: ./expt host pass user keyfile"
    exit 2
}

   set host [lindex $argv 0]
   set pass [lindex $argv 1]
   set user [lindex $argv 2]
   set keyfile [lindex $argv 3]

   spawn ssh-copy-id -i $keyfile $user@$host
   expect "assword:"
   send "$pass\n"
   expect eof
```

3) Now loop through the array which holds your hosts and send the `id_rsa.pub`

```
for host in "${hosts[@]}" ; do ./expt "$host" Y0urPassword username ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ; done
```

Wait until the public key is copied to all hosts.

Comment: I'll try this as soon as possible to gave you reply. But i don't like to store my password in a file. If there is no solution then ill go this way :).

Comment: You can use  password as an argument and pass it to the filename

Comment: That was my idea to use enter pass and then use it as variable, but i can't find a way to use it with the command or when prompt for pass to get that variable. For example when the command execute it will ask me for password and to read id from a variable, or something like that ... im lost on how to solve this :)

Comment: @user3523605  see my updated answer

Comment: yes i see it ill try as soon as possible and inform you. The last time i try i get an error like wrong directory something like that. But let me fix all that and try again.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Same thing, on every server it ask me for the password....

Comment: @user3523605 You need to use the same username + password for all servers. It will not work if destination hosts have different usernames / passwords.  It worked in my scenario.

Comment: Yes it is the same user/pass. I have made my rsa key with ssh-keygen -t rsa. Making my pub and priv key with the password "passtest123". All this is store in /root/.ssh/ Deploying on all servers my pub key. So when i ssh root@serv1.com it ask me for password ( the one when i create the keys ) and he look up if the pub key is on etc. Now the whole idea is the guy say to me deploy my pub key to all the servers. And as you told me i did. The script is right but i think we are missing something.

Comment: I have put the "serv1.com and serv2.com" in a file. Make the script and execute as you told me. It works fine it deploy the keys, but when it goes to serv2.com it ask me for the password again. I'll take a look again tomorrow morning its too late now :). But i think its the for loop we are missing or something similar. Again thanks for replying ...

Comment: @user3523605  Did you put  `serv1.com   serv2.com`  in the file and are these lines terminated by a newline? Let's say you put all hosts in the file called  `hosts.txt`  If that's the case then the for loop changes slightly. E.g:  `while read -r host; do ./expt "$host" yourpassword username ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub; done < hosts.txt`

Comment: I have put serv1.com and server2.com in file with new line, like this:`server1.com` newline `server2.com`
I'll try this again and inform you.

Comment: Hi, i have try and same thing happening..On every executed command i have to put the password and also i forgot to mention that when i put the password is in clear text form not blank. My password is with special characters so maybe that is the problem? For example this i my password #$somethin123, but i have put the "" and still nothing

Comment: You need to put the password in single quotes. That is `'#$something123'` If you have a `!` in your password then you need to first  `set +H`  which denotes `histexpand`.  It would be easier if you can post the output when you run the command.

Comment: Hi, same thing, and also i notes that the key's are not add to the remote hosts, instead, they are added in my machine, my /root/.ssh/ :). I don't know how to add a file here so ill past some lines i hope you can read it or someone can edit this post:

Comment: This is the first part
`while read -r host; do ./expt "$host" '@#Password23' root key.pub; done < hosts.txt
spawn ssh-copy-id -i key.pub root@host1.com
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s),to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa': @#Password23
`

Comment: This is continue part from upper post:
`Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa': @#Password23
spawn ssh-copy-id -i key.pub root@host2.com
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
Enter passphrase for key './key': ^C`

Comment: @user3523605 If you are being asked to enter a passphrase because you secured your private key with a passphrase, then yes it will ask you each time. There is no way you can pass the passphrase to the encrypted private key. At least I don't know if that is possible

Comment: Yes that is true, but the solution for this was if it ask me for the password, the expect part should play the roll. We are putting the password as variable and should use it when it needed. I'm right ? And i don't know way it stores on my pc it should go on a remote. Somehow it doesn't read the host file or something but that is little mistake, that part don't worry's me. I need to find a way to automatically put my password as it ask. I don't understand way expect don't work here.

Comment: This is very VERY stupid of me! :) i now see that i just make copy past of what you tell me and as i look at the expect script i notes that for the password we are expecting to be "assword" as word instead of something else, in this situation i put `Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/` so now expect works perfect but instead the key to be on a remote key it stores on my machine in /root/.ssh/ and when i run it like you say with while on every next remote machine it ask me for the new key to enter `Enter passphrase for key'` --- new key

Comment: Ok now everything work fine with for loop but now im trying to put this everything in one script...so when i put this in for loop with already given arguments it doesn't get the arguments ....

Comment: This solution only works when the host has already been added to known_hosts. What about edge cases where the box has never been visited and the user is prompted with, "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?"

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally i have got this. Now work perfect. In the script after the for loop and do i add this line:

```
/usr/bin/expect <<EOD
```

and the conde of the expect procedure like:

```
spawn ssh-copy-id -i test.pub root@<name_host>
        expect "Enter passphrase for key"
        send "$pass\n"
        expect eof
EOD
```

and works perfect !

Thanks again for explain and helping val0x00ff

;)